# How to differentiate between Database connection failure errors vs other exceptions in DataAccessException in Spring Data Jpa

Tags: java, exception, spring-data-jpa, spring-kafka

I need to identify Database connection failure exceptions vs other exceptions and handle accordingly inside my kafka listener error handler. As everything is converted to DataAcccessException in Spring Data JPA, I am just wondering what exceptions are throws when connection failure occurs while app is running.
Work environment: Spring boot 2.x, Spring data jpa, spring-kafka, Java 8

Answer (score 2):

DataAccessException is only the root of the hierarchy, check out the subclasses, Spring is categorizing the type of exception for you already.

It sounds like you're interested in instances of 
TransientDataAccessException, which covers connection and locking issues, its [description](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/TransientDataAccessException.html) is:

> Root of the hierarchy of data access exceptions that are considered transient - where a previously failed operation might be able to succeed when the operation is retried without any intervention by application-level functionality.

There is NonTransientDataAccessException, which is stuff like data integrity errors (RI checks and constraints failing):

> Root of the hierarchy of data access exceptions that are considered non-transient - where a retry of the same operation would fail unless the cause of the Exception is corrected.

and RecoverableDataAccessException (transaction problems):

> Data access exception thrown when a previously failed operation might be able to succeed if the application performs some recovery steps and retries the entire transaction or in the case of a distributed transaction, the transaction branch. At a minimum, the recovery operation must include closing the current connection and getting a new connection.

The apidoc shows which subclasses exist for each of these so you can get an idea of what kinds of errors are being described.